# Safari extension is opening as file in safari browser version 5, mac OS snow leopard

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, safari, safari-extension

I am new to safari extension development. I have developed extension using extension builder and packed and uploaded to server. I have gave the link to download extension as shown below in my website:

```
<a href="http://example.com/extension/myextension.safariextz">Install button</a>
```

while clicking a tag in safari browser it is opening as file as shown in below picture

[image: ][1]].

Issue in below browser and os

browser: safari 5.1

os : mac os X snow leopard

I also tried in mac os X Mountainlion and mac os X mavericks with safari 6.1 and 7 respectively it is working fine and the extension is installed properly.

please advice me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you are serving the file as text/plain which causes the browser to show the content. 
You should force the client-browser to download the file, add this to you .htaccess:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .safariextz
```